# How do I transform and group a set of maps in elixir?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Given this data structure:

```
[
  %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Foo", score: 4 }, %{ description: "Bar", score: 5 } ] },
  %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Baz", score: 3 }, %{ description: "Foo", score: 4 } ] },
  %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Bar", score: 1 }, %{ description: "Baz", score: 1 } ] }
]
```

I would like to create a set of new maps for each unique `description` with a summation of the corresponding scores. Like this:

```
[
  %{ description: "Foo", score: 8 },
  %{ description: "Bar", score: 6 },
  %{ description: "Baz", score: 4 }
]
```

One could break this down to the following:

1. Iterate through initial dataset
2. Build a set of maps for each unique `description`
3. Reduce set with a summation function
4. Build set of maps with new results for each group.

I imagine this process will involve a combination of `reduce` and `map`, but what I'm struggling with is the initial grouping that is necessary to run a summation function. An idiomatic elixir solution would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Enum.flat_map/2` and `Enum.group_by/2`:

```
list = [
  %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Foo", score: 4 }, %{ description: "Bar", score: 5 } ] },
  %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Baz", score: 3 }, %{ description: "Foo", score: 4 } ] },
  %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Bar", score: 1 }, %{ description: "Baz", score: 1 } ] }
]

list
|> Enum.flat_map(fn x -> x.collection end)
|> Enum.group_by(fn x -> x.description end)
|> Enum.map(fn {key, value} ->
    %{description: key, score: value |> Enum.map(fn x -> x.score end) |> Enum.sum}
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[%{description: "Bar", score: 6}, %{description: "Baz", score: 4},
 %{description: "Foo", score: 8}]
```

Note that since `group_by` uses a `Map` under the hood, this does *not* preserve the order of items in the resulting list.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. No need to keep ordering since sorting can always be included after this grouping operation. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
defmodule Group do

  @groups [
    %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Foo", score: 4 }, %{ description: "Bar", score: 5 } ] },
    %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Baz", score: 3 }, %{ description: "Foo", score: 4 } ] },
    %{ collection: [ %{ description: "Bar", score: 1 }, %{ description: "Baz", score: 1 } ] }
  ]

  def transform(groups \\ @groups) do
    groups 
    |> Enum.reduce([], fn group, list -> list ++ group[:collection] end)
    |> Enum.group_by(&(&1.description), &(&1.score))
    |> Enum.map(fn {key, v} -> {key, Enum.sum(v)} end)
    |> Enum.into(%{})
  end
end

iex(24)> Group.transform
%{"Bar" => 6, "Baz" => 4, "Foo" => 8}
```

Comment: Ah, not exactly what you asked for ... and @Dogbert was faster as usual :-)

Comment: Ya, just a bit different than what I need, but thanks for taking the time. Perhaps a useful approach for another time :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Enum.reduce(collections, %{}, fn(%{collection: list}, acc) -> 
  Map.merge(acc, Enum.reduce(list, %{}, fn(map, acc2) -> Map.put(acc2, map[:description], map) end), fn(_k, v1, v2) -> 
    Map.put(v1, :score, v1[:score] + v2[:score]) 
  end) 
end) 
|> Map.values()
```

The last line `|> Map.values()` is optional to me. I'd remove this line so that you have a unique key and a map which seems better to me.